# bash の再起動は、 bash の中から行えますか？

Tags: bash

.bashrc を書き換えた場合など(ただ、それに限らず)、 bash を再起動したくなる場合があります。

そのような場合において、 bash の再起動は bash の中から行えますか？

Comment: やるとすれば `exec bash -l` ですかね…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

再起動ではないので回答になってないかもしれませんがbashrcなどは再起動せずとも読み込めます。

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

あとこれも再起動ではありませんが新しくログインシェルを起動する事でも読み込めるので、ファイルを変更して確認したいときなどはそうしてます。

```
$ bash -l
```

Answer (score 1):

スクリプトをそのまま叩けばいい、というのが @take88 さんの回答でしたが、再起動に近いのは `exec` を利用することであること、また`-l`の取り扱いについて最近理解が深まったのでまとめておきます。

## `.bashrc` を再度読み込みたい場合

```
exec bash
```

なにが起こるか: 現在の bash (のプロセス) を、新たに起動した `bash` のプロセスで置き換える。`.bashrc` が再度読み込まれる。 `.bashrc` は複数回 exec を実行しても問題ないような内容のみを記述するべきであるので、これで基本的に問題がない。

## `.bash_profile` (もしくは `.profile`) を読み込みたい場合

@argus さんもコメントで仰っているように、

```
exec bash -l
```

を実行すると、 bash は「ログインシェルとして起動したときの初期化処理」を行いながらプロセスを再起動できる。その際に、`.bash_profile`が読み込まれる。([参考](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html))

ただ、この初期化処理はただ一回だけ、ログイン時にのみ実行されることを想定した記述がされるべきところであるので、そこは自己責任で行われるべき。

具体的にこの挙動を観測するには、 `.bash_profile` (or, `.profile`) で PATH の追加処理を行っていた場合には、 exec の度にその追加処理が走ることになっているなどから確認できる。

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/vagrant/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
$ exec bash -l
$ echo $PATH
/home/vagrant/bin:/home/vagrant/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
$
```

(ただ、 tmux とかだと問答無用でログインシェルとして起動して、 (i) ログイン時 (ii) tmux 起動時 の２回 .profile は実行されたりしているので、複数回実行されても大丈夫なように、 そもそも .profile は記述するべきなのかもしれない)